# Automobile ignition coil (spark coil)

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, magnetics

**Question:** How is this possible to get 1:1000 electric potential scale while primary/secondary loop scale is only about 1:100?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible because the ignition coil is not a "normal" transformer

> An ignition coil is essentially an autotransformer with a high ratio
>   of secondary to primary windings. By "Autotransformer", I mean that
>   the primary and secondary windings are not actually separated - they
>   share a few of the windings. The ratio of secondary to primary turns
>   in an ignition coil is somewhere around 100:1. The ignition coil is
>   operated directly off a 12 volt source. However, the ignition coil
>   does not work like an ordinary transformer. An ordinary transformer
>   will produce output current at the same time that input current is
>   applied. An ignition coil actually does most of its work acting as an
>   inductor. When the ignition coil is connected to the battery, the
>   inductor is 'charged' with current. It takes a few milliseconds for
>   the current to build up the magnetic field - this on account of
>   reverse voltage caused by the increase in magnetic field. During this
>   short charging period, maybe a thousand volts are produced at the high
>   voltage terminal, not enough to actually cause a spark.
>
> The actual spark is generated when the breaker contacts open. For an
>   ideal inductor, the current and voltage relate by:
>
> V = L dI
>
> Where V is voltage, L is inductance (in henrys) and dI is the
>   rate of change of the current.
>
> Thus, seeing that L is constant for the inductor, the abrupt change in
>   current will cause a very large voltage to be produced. This produces
>   a very short, very high voltage spike. Of course, the change in
>   current is on the primary side, but because the primary and secondary
>   coils have a large mutual inductance (this is where the transformer
>   part comes in), you get a spike on the order of 100 or more volts on
>   the primary, and 10000 volts on the secondary. Even the primary side
>   of the coil can give you a bit of a jolt if you hold the wires while
>   disconnecting power. Also note that any contacts you will use will get
>   a lot of sparks, also on account of this.

From http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/cannon/sparky.html